# How to properly store a list of data in SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, list, serialization

I'm still wrapping my head around some basic concepts of SQL. More so I'm trying to understand how I'd manage of list of data in a row. There's a possibility it'll be different lengths of names so I don't see how I could have separate columns for all that data.

```
['John','Bill','Henry','Roxanne']
['James','Sandy','May']
```

I could store it as a string but my instinct says that's a bad idea. I could serialize it but there's a possibility these lists could contains hundreds of items and I don't know how much stress it can take.

How can I do this efficiently? And a more important question, where can I learn concepts like this?

Update:

An example of data I expect to store in a row:

```
Matthew | 12-07-2013 | ['James','Sandy','May'] | matthew@whatever.com
```

Comment: Your instincts are spot on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past (and no guarantees this is the most efficient method) is to use a second table, and link it back to the original.

So instead of the single table containing entries like:

```
name    | date       | users                   | email
Matthew | 12-07-2013 | ['James','Sandy','May'] | matthew@whatever.com
```

You'd have two tables, one with your primary info:

```
name    | date       | email
Matthew | 12-07-2013 | matthew@whatever.com
```

and one to link:

```
index   | name       | user
1       | Matthew    | James
2       | Matthew    | Sandy
3       | Matthew    | May
```

Which you could then join together as needed.

Comment: I love the visual. Definitely able to understand this now. My counter question is if say James like the color `red` would I add it to that second table or would I create a new table and set the primary id to `James` and then references it again like you did above? And if so, wouldn't that over time create a load on the mysql server from too many queries linked together?

Comment: "wouldn't that over time create a load on the mysql server from too many queries linked together?" Pretty much the main purpose of MySQL is to link queries like this together (table joins). That's why it's called a "relational database": each table represents a separate relation. So yes, it will create a load, but a manageable one provided you understand the tools you have.

Comment: Glad it helped! In answer to your counter question, it depends. Will the original table (which currently has only an entry for Matthew), have an entry for one of each of what I called "users"? In that case, just add a column "colors" to that table.  If the names of the people who will appear in the "name" and "user" column are fundamentally different, then yes, you will need a third table with the "user" column as the index.

Answer (score 1):

Create a second table with two (or more) columns, one (or all but one) of which identifies which row in the first table you're talking about[*]. The last column identifies a name in Matthew's list. Create 3 rows in this table for Matthew: one each with James, Sandy and May.

Of course it is possible to store the names as one big string field, but you should not do that if you're not confident that the database itself doesn't need to consider them separate entities. And even if you're confident now, you might change your mind later and have to fix it.

> a more important question, where can I learn concepts like this?

Any SQL tutorial should cover it.

[*] I can't tell you how to do this because I don't know enough about your data. Maybe "Matthew" uniquely identifies the row (and the list of names are Matthew's friends). Maybe "Matthew" plus the date does (and the list of names is the people Matthew had meetings with on that day). Maybe nothing does, and your first table needs a synthetic primary key so that the second table can refer to it.